# Numpy broadcasting with comparison operator; cyclic iteration

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have implemented a cyclic iteration function in two ways:

```
def Spin1(n, N) :           # n - current state, N - highest state
    value = n + 1   
    case1 = (value > N) 
    case2 = (value <= N)
    return case1 * 0 + case2 * value

def Spin2(n, N) :
    value = n + 1   
    if value > N :
        return 0
    else : return value
```

These functions are identical regarding the returned results. However the second function is not broadcasting-capable for a numpy array. So to test the first function I run this:

```
import numpy

AR1 = numpy.zeros((3, 4), dtype = numpy.uint32)
AR1[1,2] = 5
print AR1
print Spin1(AR1,5)
```

Magically it works, and that is so sweet. So I see exactly what I want:

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 5 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]
[[1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 0 1]
 [1 1 1 1]]
```

Now with the second function `print Spin2(AR1,5)` it fails with this error:

```
if value > N
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. 
Use a.any() or a.all()
```

And it's clear why, since `if Array` statement is nonsence. So for now I just used the first variant. But when I look at those functions I have a strong feeling that in the first function there are much more mathematical operations so I don't lose the hope that I can do something about optimising it. 

**Questions:**
1. Is it possible to optimise the function `Spin1` to do less operations **or** how do I use the function `Spin2` in broadcasting mode (possibly without making my code too ugly)? Extra question: What would be the fastest way to do that manipulation with an array?

2. Is there some standard Python function which does the same calculation (not implicitly broadcasting-capable) and how it is correctly called - "cyclic increment" probably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Spin1` follows a well established pattern in array oriented languages (e.g. APL, MATLAB) for 'vectorizing' a function like `Spin2`.  You create one or more booleans (or 0/1 arrays) to represent the various states the array elements can take, and then construct the output by multiplication and summation.

For example, to avoid divide-by-zero problems, I have used:

```
1/(x+(x==0))
```

A variation on this is to use a boolean index array to select array elements that should be changed.  In this case, you want to return `value`, but with selected elements 'rolled over'.

```
def Spin3(n, N) :           # n - current state, N - highest state
    value = n + 1
    value[value>N] = 0
    return value
```

In this case, the indexing approach is simpler, and seems to fit the program logic better.  It may be faster, but I can't guarantee that.  It's good to keep both approaches in mind.

Comment: Yes yes yes, that is exactly what I thought about. So I thought how do I do something for elements defined by this boolean mask without indexing. Your variant looks best for me, it's clear and fits my tasks good, since I make now a lot of image processing and its all about bitmasks. I've just found another similar numpy function `np.putmask`  which could be also useful for mixing arrays within a bitmask.

Answer (score 2):

There is a numpy function for this: [np.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [590]: AR1
Out[590]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 5, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint32)

In [591]: np.where(AR1 >= 5, 0, 1)
Out[591]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

---

So, you could define:

```
def Spin1(n, N) :        
    value = n + 1   
    return np.where(value > N, 0, value)
```

---

NumPy also provides a way to turn normal Python functions into [ufuncs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html):

```
def Spin2(n, N) :
    value = n + 1   
    if value > N :
        return 0
    else : return value

Spin2 = np.vectorize(Spin2)
```

So that you can now call `Spin2` on arrays:

```
In [595]: Spin2(AR1, 5)
Out[595]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

However, np.vectorize mainly provides syntactic sugar. There is still a Python function call being made for each array element, which makes `np.vectorized` ufuncs [no faster than equivalent code using Python for-loops](http://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion@scipy.org/msg00587.html).

Comment: Thank a lot, +1 for `np.where` it does exactly what my function does.

Answer (score 0):

I put here some feedback as an answer, just not to mess up with the question. So I've done timing tests on various functions and it turns out that assigning by a boolean mask in this case is the fastest variant (hpaulj's answer). `np.where` was 1.4 times slower and `np.vectorize(Spin2)` was 15 times slower. Now just out of curiousity I wanted to test this with loops, so I made up this algorithm for testing:

```
AR1 = numpy.zeros((rows, cols), dtype = numpy.uint32)
while d <= 100:
    Buf = numpy.zeros_like(AR1)
    r = 0
    c = 0
    while (r < rows) :
        while (c < cols) :
            temp = AR1[r, c] + 1
            if temp > 5 : 
                Buf[r, c] = 1
            else : Buf[r, c] = temp 
            c += 1
        r += 1
        c = 0
    AR1 = Buf
    d += 1
```

I am not sure, but it seems to be very straightforward implementation of all the above mentioned functions. But it is sooo slow, almost 300 times slower. I have read similar questions on SO, but still I don't get it, WHY is it so? And what exactly is causing this slowdown. Here I have intentionally made up a buffer to avoid read-write functions on the same elements and do not do memory clean up. So what can be more simple, I am confused. Don't want to open a new question, since it was asked few times already, so probably someone will put comments or has good links clarifying this?